# Can powershell script be run using REST API / JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a way to invoke and execute a .ps1 file using REST/JSOM?

I am hoping to deploy a SharePoint Hosted App that runs a powershell script on the server.

Comment: dont think so, but you can call a custom service which will execute the csom code to deploy sharepoint hosted app

Comment: @GautamSheth the sp hosted app should have the provision to invoke and run powershell scripts. So, the options with me are Rest and JSOM. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: i dont think its possible to execute ps1 script from REST/JSOM. You can create a custom webservice(web api) on azure. This service will deploy the sp hosted app using CSOM code.

Comment: did the above mentioned solution work with SharePoint App?

Comment: @Poornima with slight alteration, it should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes,** You can call your executable powershell scripts *.ps1 using REST api as HTTP GET is supported by all programming language (javascript in your case).

This  msdn blog will help you:

[Simple HTTP api for Executing PowerShell Scripts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/09/29/simple-http-api-for-executing-powershell-scripts/)

Comment: Thanks, DvG. Looks promising. I am trying this. Will choose this as answer if it works :)